# If one person login and closed the broswer, again opening link we should not login again...i should be in loggedin page

Tags: python, flask-login

If one person login and closed the broswer, again opening link we should not login again...i should be in loggedin page

Give me suggest what we have to do

Comment: My opinion - > Add another remember me field - if checked let them be logged in, if not should be logged out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.